# jQuery Mobile number formatting?

Tags: jquery, formatting, numbers

I am pulling in a bunch of mobile numbers from a JSON file that are pulled in elsewhere so i cannot chance the document formatting unfortunately so i have to find a work-a-round!

It come in looking like: 0404013278

I need to format it: 0404-013-278

As HTML it looks like this:

```
<p class="mobile-number">0404013278</p>
```

Is there some kind of plugin that i could use or does someone know a short piece of script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uh6rN/4/). You can write your own simple jQuery plugin as below.

```
   $.fn.formatMobileNumber = function () { 
      var s =  $(this).text();
      var s2 = (""+s).replace(/\D/g, '');
      var m = s2.match(/^(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/);
      $(this).text((!m) ? null : ""  + m[1] + "-" + m[2] + "-" + m[3] );
  }

 $(".mobile-number").formatMobileNumber(); ​
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your phone inside an input and use .mask() function from [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin

```
    $('selector').mask("999-999-9999");
```

Comment: `mask` ? Some kind of plugin or what ?